# how can i rename files with different names at once in python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, filenames

```
path = '/Users/my/path/tofile'
files = os.listdir(path)
names= ["GAT4", "LO", "sds"]
    for filename in files:
            if files.startswith("sample" + str[i]):
                original_file= os.path.join(path, filename)
                new_file= os.path.join(path, names.join([str(i), '.html']))
                os.rename(original_file, new_file)
```

**i have many files and i wanna rename all of them using a python code that changes the name depending on a given name from a list:**
*for example i have a list of x = [sample1, sample236, GAT988] and my files are named like: exp1.html exp2.html exp3.html*
*how can i make the files names become GAT988.html instead of exp3.html?`enter code here`
thank you.*

Comment: What is the exact logic you're asking for? Please provide a clear mapping between input filenames and output (renamed) filenames. Thanks!

Comment: what is the logic of renaming your files ?

Comment: ok sorry i was not clear, what im asking is if my input file is renamed like: sample1.html sample2.html sample3.html i want my output files renamed as GAT2.html, LSD.html and kp.html.. and i thought maybe i could change the names by using lists and os.rename but i m confused.

Comment: @AbhishekKulkarni the logic is i wanna rename them with specific names from a list so it is kind of the opposite from if you name them depending on the index or enumerations.. i hope you got it

Comment: Try this:  `source_file_list = ['exp1.html', 'exp2.html', 'exp3.html']`, `dest_name_list = ['sample1', 'sample236', 'GAT988']`, where lists lineup positionally.  Index both lists using same index starting at 0. Extract source file ext from source file and append to end of item in dest.  Call `os.rename(source, dest)` where `source` is source filename and `dest` is dest entry with appended file ext. Repeat for subsequent index values til shorter list exhausted. Major Caveat:  Lists must lineup nicely.